# xCode6 how to apply blur/vibrancy effect properly in storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, ios8, blur, xcode6

I'm trying out the new "Visual effect with Blur" in xCode and am noticing the visual artifact in the attached image. I tried different combinations of constraints and see that

[image]

Here's the issue I'm seeing - the UILabel's frame is outlined in a different color. **How can I make sure that the label has a transparent background, but still gets the vibrancy effect when using "Visual Effect with Blur and Vibrancy"?**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both the UILabel and any view behind has Background set to Clear/Default color.

[image]